# Shut down windows 10 machine using command line

Tags: windows, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Windows 10 and WSL are installed in my laptop. What are the commands I should use to shut down and sleep the laptop using command line. And Since I windows 10 and WSL are worked as dual mode, What console is the best one? command prompt or wsl? 
thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Command Prompt:**

```
shutdown /s /t 1 /f
```

**Powershell:**

```
Stop-Computer -Force
```